# Java app can't connect to rabbitMQ from the same docker container

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq

I have a sample Spring Boot app that produce message:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000)
public void test() throws Exception {
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost("localhost");
    try (Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
         Channel channel = connection.createChannel()) {
        channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
        String message = "Hello Rabbit!";
        channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME, null, message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + message + "'");
    }
}
```

It is dockerized:

```
FROM openjdk:11 as jdkbase
FROM jdkbase

COPY target/RabbitMQtester-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /run/RabbitMQtester-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
#ADD target/sfida-1.0.0.jar /run/sfida-1.0.0.jar

ENTRYPOINT java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar /run/RabbitMQtester-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I need to build an image containing both RabbitMQ and my app. Here is docker-compose.yml for this task:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  mytestapp:
    build: .
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.8.3-management-alpine
    hostname: localhost
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: guest
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: guest
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
```

When i start the resulting image, i can access rabbitMQ admin page from my host. Also, i can run my app from the host and it'll access rabbitMQ.
But my app, which is in the container/image, can't access RabbitMQ (it throws "Connection refused (Connection refused)" errors)
What is wrong with my configurations?

UPD: I've also tried to change docker-compose.yml to this (and connection in my app to `factory.setHost("rabbitmq");` )

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  mytestapp:
    build: .
    networks:
      - some-net
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.8.3-management-alpine
    hostname: rabbitmq
    networks:
      - some-net
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: guest
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: guest
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
networks:
  some-net:
    driver: bridge
```

and to this:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  mytestapp:
    build: .

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.8.3-management-alpine
    hostname: rabbitmq
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: guest
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: guest
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
```

but result is the same...

Comment: Are you bridging the networks in your `docker-compose` file?

Comment: Also what type of OS are you using?

Comment: 1. this is my whole docker-compose.yml file; 2. MacOS 11.2.3

Comment: Maybe using `localhost` as hostname is causing some problems. Try renaming `hostname` in docker-compose and `factory.setHost` to something like rabbitmq-container

Comment: I've tried it (see the upd) but still the same result with errors :(

Answer (score 1):

The RabbitMQ service is by default accessible using the name of the docker service `rabbitmq` (when you remove `hostname: localhost`) from other services in the same stack (provided they are configured with the same network, in this case the default). So you should replace `factory.setHost("localhost");` with `factory.setHost("rabbitmq");` and remove `hostname: localhost`.

You did specify `hostname: localhost`, so one could assume RabbitMQ can be accessed using `localhost` hostname from the `mytestapp` service, but since it's not working it's very likely conflicting with the default loopback and resolving to `127.0.0.1` instead.

Comment: I've tried it (see the upd) but still the same result with errors :(

Comment: Just a concern because I ran into this as well, are you specifying the `--build` flag when brining your docker compose up? Because otherwise it only builds the first time. You can verify this by adding some logging, to see if the changes are applied.

So: `docker-compose up --build`